# GCC not found when running from script

Tags: macos, bash, gcc, nginx

I am trying to make a script to get and compile nginx on OS X. When I run `./configure --prefix=.`  from terminal I get what you would expect, but when I put it into a bash script, I get:

```
checking for OS
 + Darwin 13.0.0 x86_64
checking for C compiler ... not found

./configure: error: C compiler cc is not found

make: *** No rule to make target `build', needed by `default'.  Stop.
```

Any ideas about what would cause GCC to go missing?

Comment: Search SO for your error message `error: C compiler cc is not found`, there are a couple of other posts about the same issue, one of those solutions is likely to help. And by search SO, I mean `google` along with `stackoverflow.com` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the full path of cc (execute `which cc`).
2. Extend the path in your script (for example `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`)

Comment: `which cc` gives me `/usr/bin/cc` and I can echo PATH from my script and it gives me `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Also run `pwd` from the script and make it the same as the interactive path

Comment: Apparently it was a version issue that wasn't giving me any useful error data. Thank you for your help.